# How can I add a red asterisk in a placeholder?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The placeholder should show Enter a name* with a white text but the * red.
I'm using Bootstrap 4 in Chrome. My HTML and CSS code are these:

```css
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder::after {
    color: red;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 50px;
    content: "*";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control py-4" style="background: #273a71; color: white; border: 0;">
```

Comment: you can use label and required to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Use span or label instead of placeholder (Using span, in case you want label and placeholder)
2. Use on focus to hide span with css

```css
.placeholder{
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}

.placeholder:after{
  content: '*';
  color: red
}


.form-control:focus + .placeholder { 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text"  class="form-control py-4" style="background: #273a71; color: white; border: 0;" required="required">
<span class="placeholder">Your Name</span>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GzQVev

Comment: After typing something and click outside of input, focus is getting removed and you see placeholder and input value on top of eachother.